# string with HTML - replace elements/part of string (??Regex)

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, replace

... I try to explain it in another way. I have a string like this:

```
string myText = "... <p class="MsoNormal">bla gezeichnete bla zuzustellen.</p><p>10.0080</p><p class="MsoNormal">text text text</p><p class="p--heading-2"><span class="anchor--on anchorname--160p001200">Schriftliche Bearbeitung</span</p><p>1.02</p><p>Eine blablabla text text</p><p>1.010</p><p>Ein text text (look <a xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="replace" xlink:role="17160" xlink:actuate="onRequest" xlink:href="link/a1000-text.xml">10.0060</a>) text text text</p> ..."
```

Now I want edit a part of string (c#) -> for example:

```
myText = myText.Replace("<p class="p--heading-2"><span class="anchor--on anchorname--160p00">Schriftliche Bearbeitung</span</p>", "<h2><a name="anchorname">Schriftliche Bearbeitung</a></p>");
```

The problem are the variable values (for excample the anchorname needs different values) and so I can´t replace the string.

Comment to first answer: I don´t want to use third-party supplier software (respective HtmlAgilityPack).

Are there any ideas for solution? If a regex the best solution, how the regex looks like?
thanks.

Comment: I can't see at all how you got from the first string to the second. Where does `ankername` come from? Why `<h3>`? Plus, of course, you really don't want to use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: what are undefined signs..and why use regex for this

Comment: As a general rule do not use regex to parse html

Answer (score 0):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) not regex

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='p--heading-2']");
foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in nodes)
{
    var newNodeStr = htmlNode.InnerText;
    var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<h3><a>"+newNodeStr+"</a></h3>");
    htmlNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, htmlNode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Unfortunately I'm not sure whether the way is helpful. Could you please explain how I can use the "HtmlDocument" with a string? Which namespace is "HtmlDocument"?